# Minimum rep to ask questions

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, questions, reputation

Most of the subjective questions on StackOverflow relied on being popular enough to have a lot of replies. However, at some point there'll probably be a flood of questions and the answers will be split between them.

When this site goes into public beta, I suggest requiring a minimum amount of rep (300?) to ask questions.

Comment: I upvote the question, because it is completely clear and useful, for example, one can read answers and decide, that it is really bad idea.

Comment: The unofficial policy on Meta.StackOverflow has been that a down vote means "I don't like this idea" not that the question is not clear. (See: [Why are people downvoting my question on Meta?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42558/why-are-people-downvoting-my-question-on-meta))

Comment: How do you build rep if not by asking questions?

Comment: Answering them.

Comment: Sure some people would have dumb questions, but what about the people that have legitamite good ones?

Comment: Even if there are lots of good ones, any answers will be split between them.

Comment: @Simon Brown. This is a very bad idea. The Stack Exchange websites will lose a lot of recurring visitors if you require 300 rep just to ask a question. Nobody wants to answer questions all day long, every day until their reputation hits 300 (which could take as little as 2-3 days (given the daily max of 250 on S/O) or as long as 1week, or even a month!), just to be able to ask 1 simple question. This has to be the worst idea I've ever heard.

Answer (score 14):

Maybe downvoting and moderating is enough. 
If there will be lack of moderators and questions flood, we can just (e.g.) autodelete all questions, that were downvoted enough, or make vote proposals for deletion, merge, or somewhat, so, community will decide, whose question will die or merge.

But it is too cruel to forbid to ask questions on Q&A site.

Comment: `But it is too cruel to forbid to ask questions on Q&A site.` Agreed.

Comment: Being able to ask questions is the entire reason for StackExchange.

Answer (score 5):

That's pretty contrary to how all the other StackExchange/Trilogy sites are run. The purpose of these sites is to provide a mechanism for anyone to ask a question for which they need an answer to, and if they have to be an active member of the community to even post a question, that purpose is circumvented.

Answer (score 2):

We don't want barriers to adoption, particularly in the beta stage. We seem to deal with these things pretty well on Stack Overflow, with gentle (and sometimes not so gentle) reminders to n00bs of the etiquette (checking for dupes / accepting answers etc.)

Remember we want to have users on this site and preferably a lot of them.

I think that more experienced users giving out those reminders should be sufficient, at least unless this becomes a real problem, rather than a potential problem.